Regex function that identifies either first char or whole word
I'm trying to develop a regex pattern to use in a for loop. I have two lists - one is a cleaned set of keywords from a document, the other are a set of tags that I want to used the cleaned text to match to. Here's an example of what it would look like:
text_list = ['item1', '3000', '3100', 'item2', '4543', '4643']
tags_list = ['item1 3000 series', 'item 2 4000 series']

Because of the way the documents are written, the tags are not always connected. 'item1', '3000', and '3100' all relate to each other and really translate to 'item1 3000' and 'item1 3100', but the author did not write it that way. I'd like to be able to have an item like '3000' or '3100' and match it to 'item1 3000 series'.
I assume to do this I would need a regex that either matches the entire word ('3000' to the '3000' in 'item 3000 series') or the first char of a word ('3100' to the '3' in '3000' in 'item 3000 series).
Is this possible using regex? I've been struggling to develop a pattern that can achieve this.

You can use a regexp like \b(item1|3\d+)\b to match either the word item1 or a number beginning with 3.

What if 'item 2 4000 series' in tags_list is replaced with 'item 2 40000 series'? When you give an example it's generally helpful to include the desired result, even if you think it should be obvious.

@CarySwoveland I'm not sure what you mean by this. The tag's list is static and comes from a taxonomy in a different system. I've anonymized this content for safety. I did provide the desired result in the text.

You do not need regex if you are merely looking for substring, just use in keyword as follows
text_list = ['item1', '3000', '3100', 'item2', '4543', '4643']
tags_list = ['item1 3000 series', 'item 2 4000 series']
for text in text_list:
    for tag in tags_list:
        if text in tag:
            print("Match for", text, "is", tag)

gives output
Match for item1 is item1 3000 series
Match for 3000 is item1 3000 series


If you're looking to identify based on the series number, you should be able to check against the pattern /3\d{3}/ to identify a 4 digit number starting with 3 for example. So for each tag, you can have a regex to match like:
/3\d{3}/ would trigger "item1 3000 series"
/4\d{3}/ would trigger "item2 4000 series"
If you need more specificity, you can add /item1 3\d{3}/ if they're reliably in sequence.
Or if you want to find them in the same sentence but optionally with other things between, you could do something like this /item1 [^.]+3\d{3}/ to identify "item1" followed by any amount of text that doesn't include a period, then followed by a number in the format "3xxx"
